# Nginx request subset to different pool

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have an nginx server with some requests that are slower and as such could saturate a PHP FPM pool.  I don't mind if these requests get dropped and also more importantly they don't affect the normal requests.

I thought that I could create another limited PHP-FPM pool for these requests and I have done this but am struggling with the nginx side of things.

My current config looks like...

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
```

What I want to happen is that any request to certain explicit paths such as `/test/update.php` to go to another pool with the address of `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm-secondary.sock;`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure your question is written correctly? In your configuration all of the requests ending in .php will be processed to `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;`. That is, there is nothing wrong here.

Comment: Yes it is just a snippet of the config granted. And yes well spotted on the typo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do what you are looking for, but it is not tested.

```
location ~ /test/update.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm-secondary.sock;
}
```